# LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials when logging in

Tags: grails, spring-security, ldap

I'm trying to integrate our app to an active directory. I've followed this guide for starters: https://grails.org/wiki/AcegiSecurity%20Plugin%20-%20LDAP%20Tutorial but I'm getting an error:

[LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]; after logging in (connected to a LDAP directory OpenDJ)
Here's my acegi security config

```
    // LDAP/ActiveDirectory
useLdap = true
ldapRetrieveGroupRoles = false
ldapRetrieveDatabaseRoles = true
ldapSearchSubtree = true
ldapGroupRoleAttribute = 'cn'
ldapPasswordAttributeName = 'userPassword'
ldapServer = 'ldap://localhost:389' // 'ldap://ad.example.com', 'ldap://monkeymachine:389/dc=acegisecurity,dc=org'
ldapManagerDn = 'cn=Directory Manager,dc=example,dc=com'
ldapManagerPassword = 'Password123'
ldapSearchBase = 'dc=example,dc=com' // 'ou=users,dc=example,dc=com'
ldapSearchFilter = '(uid={0})' //, '(mailNickname={0})'
ldapGroupSearchBase = 'ou=company_name,dc=example,dc=com'
ldapGroupSearchFilter = 'uniquemember={0}'
ldapUsePassword = true
```

What does this error means? is my admin(ldapManagerDn) credentials wrong? or the login credentials?

Thanks

NOTE: I'm using acegi 0.5.2 because our applcation still uses grails 1.3.6

Answer (score 0):

The Directory Manager is `cn=Directory Manager`.  You can (read should) [reset the password for this root account](https://ludopoitou.com/2011/06/30/newbie-help-how-to-reset-the-directory-managers-password/), but you also should create a service account for your application.